# Missing assumption? (Convergence of random variables and characteristic functions)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Here are two exercises from my Probability book ("Probabilidade: um curso em nível intermediário", by Barry James). (I have translated them from Portuguese to English and modified them a bit.)

> Prove the following claims:
>
> $1$) If $\phi$ is a characteristic function and there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\phi (t) = 1$ for all $t$ with $|t| < \delta$, then $\phi (t) = 1 \forall t$.
>
> $2$) Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be random variables whose characteristic functions $\phi _{1}, \phi_{2}, \ldots$ converge pointwise. If there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\phi_{n} (t) \rightarrow 1$ for all $t$ with $|t| < \delta$, then $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $0 $. Hint: use Claim $1$.

I've proven Claim $1$, and I can prove Claim $2$ if I assume that the limit of the characteristic functions $\phi _{1}, \phi_{2}, \ldots$ is also a characteristic function. My question is: **is Claim $2$ still true without this additional assumption?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thanks to [Lévy's continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem), the pointwise limit is a characteristic function as soon as it is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks! We've only seen in class a "weaker" form of this theorem, namely: "$X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if $\phi_{X_{n}} (t)$ converges to $\phi_{X} (t)$ for all  $t$." I guess my teacher forgot about this when he assigned us this exercise.